# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator

Tags: sql, oracle

In a database, I am trying to pull information that is later than a specified date. I should note beforehand that the date is in an odd format: `YYYYMMDDHH24MISS##` where `##` is a two letter string which defines something useless to my query. Thus, I am using `substr` to just remove them.

My query, below, throws the following error, and I canot find out why:

> [Error Code: 920, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00920: invalid relational
>   operator

My Query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table_name
 WHERE to_date(substr(COLUMN_NAME,1,14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')) >=
       to_date('MIN_DATE', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

I have checked to make sure the dates are being defined correctly, and they are.

Example of what I have used for `MIN_DATE` is: `20140101000000`

Comment: You have more `)`'s than `(`'s.

Comment: Oh my god.. I have been stuck on this issue for half an hour.... Thanks so much @JoachimIsaksson. Isn't there a different error for too many parenthesis, though??

Comment: I agree that there should be, but sadly Oracle's error messages aren't known for always being straight forward.

Comment: Odd, I didn't even look at the parenthesis. Well, from now on that will be the first thing I check.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You have an extra parenthesis at the end of the first to_date

Answer (score 8):

You get this error in Oracle when you are missing a comparison operation, such as `=` -- as John Maillet already noted.

My concern is the second part of the `where` clause:

```
where to_date(substr(COLUMN_NAME, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') >=
                  to_date('MIN_DATE', 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

You have `MIN_DATE` in single quotes.  This is interpreted as a *string* with eight letters in it, starting with `'M'` and ending with `'E'`.  This is *not interpreted* as a variable.  Presumably you mean:

```
where to_date(substr(COLUMN_NAME, 1, 14), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') >=
                  to_date(MIN_DATE, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

You should only use single quotes for string and date constants.

I should add that you should be able to do this comparison without having to convert to dates:

```
where left(COLUMN_NAME, 14) = MIN_DATE
```